# Как сделать шкалу выбора параметра js + css

Tags: javascript, css

Друзья кто-нибудь делал такую вещь "шкала с выбором", чтобы можно было выбрать значение шкалы типо для калькулятора. Есть где пример реализации?

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 2):

Это нелегко строить с нулём, но есть некоторые примеры:

- dojo [dijit.form.slider](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dijit/form/Slider.html) (смотри третий пример)
- [dhtmlxSlider](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxSlider/)
- [jQuery slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#hotelrooms)

Answer (score 0):

В HTML5 есть тэг range
    `<input type=range min=0 max=5 value=10>`